# Selecting data from data base form two tables in iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

i want to select data from the table but those data which has same question id in the questions table and answers table.
Now it selects all the data from answers the code is shown below

```
     + (void) getAnswers:(NSString*)dbPath{

     CereniaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CereniaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *sql = "select *from answers";

     sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
            Answers *coffeeObj = [[Answers alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];


            coffeeObj.answer_text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 3)];



            NSString*testString=coffeeObj.answer_text;

            NSLog(testString);
            [appDelegate.answerArray addObject:coffeeObj];

            int mycount=[appDelegate.answerArray count];

            NSLog(@"This is int of latest %d",mycount);


            [coffeeObj release];
           }
           }
           }


     else
         sqlite3_close(database); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.
         }
```

Comment: const char *sql = "select *from answers";

Isn't that should be const char *sql = "select *from answers where questionId = ?";

Comment: @Nina then where to pass question id in code

Comment: I believe you are getting questionId from 'question' Table. Concatenate it in your sql query string. Before that try a dummy query const char *sql = "select *from answers where questionId = '2'";

Comment: yes i have tried like that its working but i want that answer should be of the same id which has same question id at run times

Comment: Then have the selected question stored in a string 'questionID'. And pass it to the query. [NSString stringWithFormat:"select *from answers where questionId = %@%@%@", @"'",questionID,@"'"];

Answer (score 0):

I suggest avoiding c level code for calling a SQLite DB - try a simple wrapper over SQLite - see https://github.com/JohnGoodstadt/EasySQLite

This will allow:

```
DataTable* result = [_db  ExecuteQuery:@"SELECT * FROM answers"];
```

It feels like you need to use a LEFT JOIN statement to answer your actual query - if you add info about your table definitions and what data you are trying to get out I can help more.